# Searching with LIKE within the value entered in the textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

The method throws an error because the entered value is too long. The value is as follows; 0121247854789652211564864456464132564641021564646543531**91**01**92**03**93**01940215646541. I need to get values between 91-92-93 in such a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best way to solve this would be with Regex:

```
string firstValue = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(textBox.Text, @"(?<=(91))\d{2}(?=(92))").Value;
string secondValue = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(textBox.Text, @"(?<=(92))\d{2}(?=(93))").Value;
```

where textBox is the name of your barcode textbox.

Comment: Probably even a single regex, if it's suitably consistent

Comment: You are right, @JJiří Baum, however i tried to keep it as linear as possible in accordance with the nature of the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not return any value

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry @Sinem Hür, it was my mistake, forgot the parentheses around 91, 92, 93 and 94. How about now?

Comment: It's done now, but there is a problem. 91-92 in the barcode is not just in one place. Example 012999210000070321021806068000012910110048286700008091019201930294000000000.The main part to be taken here is 910192019302, but it can be 91-92-93 at the beginning.

Comment: Is there always 2 digits between 91 and 92 / 92 and 93?

Comment: Yes ,always 2 digits :)

Comment: I corrected the answer, this will work, but it will only capture the first occurrence of the number group. If you want to capture multiple groups, you will have to use ```Matches``` method, and iterate through every result.

Answer (score 0):

Regex approach is for sure working solution but I think something like this would be better suited for this purpose:

```
private static string ExtractText(string text, string firstIndicator, string secondIndicator)
{
    var firstIndicatorIndex = text.IndexOf(firstIndicator);

    var secondIndicatorIndex = text.IndexOf(secondIndicator, , firstIndicatorIndex);

    string subtext = null;

    if (firstIndicatorIndex > -1 && secondIndicatorIndex > -1 && secondIndicatorIndex > firstIndicatorIndex)
    {
        subtext = text.Substring(firstIndicatorIndex + firstIndicator.Length, secondIndicatorIndex - firstIndicator.Length - firstIndicatorIndex);
    }

    return subtext;
}
```

Now, by calling this method you can extract text between two indicators.

EDIT: Length wasn't calculated correctly.

Comment: This post is hidden. It was deleted 16 mins ago by Bhargav Rao♦.
@Srecko Ristic,

The method throws an error because the entered value is too long. The value is as follows; 0121247854789652211564864456464132564641021564646543531910192039301940215646541. I need to get values between 91-92-93 in such a value.

Comment: I fixed issue with length calculation, try it now.

Comment: string sonuc = ExtractText(textBarkod.Text, "91", "92"); I'm running it as , but it doesn't give any data. The barcode is as follows; 012999210000070321021806068000012910110048286700008091019201930294000000000. The main part to be taken here is 910192019302, but it can be 91-92-93 at the beginning.

Comment: help please i am in trouble  :(

Comment: @SinemHür I modified code in such way to take next occurrence of second indicator - still you will have issue if first indicator appears more than once and that would need more elaborate solution